# How to make large arrows for Carousel in antd (ant design)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm developing a reactjs project with ant-design (antd). I'm using Carousel component with auto scrolling through some photos. I also want to add some arrows to change photos manually.

I found a way to make small buttons to the left and to the right of my Carousel. But I don't get how to make them bigger (with the same height as the photos for example), move on the photos or make visible any time (now they stay hidden until the mouse cursor is exactly on them).

Here's some code:

```
const RightArrow = () => {
    return (
        <Button icon={<RightCircleOutlined/>} size="middle"/>
    )
}

const LeftArrow = () => {
    return (
        <Button icon={<LeftCircleOutlined/>} size="middle"/>
    )
}

const SSOverview = () => {

    return (
        <Content style={{width: "100%", padding: '0 30px', fontSize: 16}}>
            <Col><Title level={1}> My Title </Title></Col>
            <Carousel autoplay autoplaySpeed={7000}
                      draggable={true} arrows={true}
                      prevArrow={LeftArrow()}
                      nextArrow={RightArrow()}>
                <div><img src={Slide2} style={{width: '100%'}} alt="Photo 1"/></div>
                <div><img src={Slide1} style={{width: '100%'}} alt="Photo 2"/></div>
                <div><img src={Slide3} style={{width: '100%'}} alt="Photo 3"/></div>
                <div><img src={Slide4} style={{width: '100%'}} alt="Photo 4"/></div>
                <div><img src={Slide5} style={{width: '100%'}} alt="Photo 5"/></div>
            </Carousel>
        //the rest of the page
        </Content>
     )
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override antd default styling with custom CSS styling. To make the buttons bigger, just add `style` property (or add `className` property and style inside CSS file). For example, you could do something like this:

```
<Button
    style={{padding: "1rem", height: "auto", width: "auto"}}
    icon={<RightCircleOutlined style={{fontSize: 60}} />}
/>
```

Here's a pen:
https://codepen.io/jaycodist/pen/mdPyqNW

Comment: I would also add that antd (and other design systems) has a lot of DOM elements nested, so I recommend using something like Chrome DevTools and always append changes to the lowest level children of the component that you are making custom styling changes to.

Comment: Yes. That's true

Comment: @JayCodist and how to find out my carousel height? height: "auto" doesn't work. Arrows stay small. When applying absolute values I got problems changing my window size.

Comment: @MarkTiukov Really? Arrows stay small even after you set the `fontSize: 60` or higher? Maybe you should reproduce this issue on a codepen. Here's an example of what I meant: https://codepen.io/jaycodist/pen/mdPyqNW

Comment: @JayCodist yes, they do stay the same. The thing is about the Carousel Component. I guess it describes the arrows but I can't find how exactly. Everything I found, I described in the question

Comment: Take a look at my code pen, see if you can reproduce your issue